# Returning all values from an API GET request that limits page size

Tags: python, api, rest

I'm currently working in an API and I'm having some issues being able to return all values of something. The API allows for page sizes up to 500 records at a time. By default it uses 25 records per "page." You can also go between pages. You can edit the page sizes by adding to the endpoint: `?page[size]={number between 1-500}`. My issue is I'm storing the values returned from the api in a dictionary and whenever I try to get the max amount of data possible if there's more than 500 records in the full population of the data I get no errors but whenever there's less than 500 I get a key error since it's expecting more data than is available. I don't want to have to guess the exact page size each and every request. Is there any easier way I can be going about this to be able to get all available data without having to request the exact amount of data for a page size? Ideally I'd want to be able to just get the max amount from whatever request always going to the upper bounds of what the request can return.

Thanks!

Here's an example of some code from the script:

```
base_api_endpoint = "{sensitive_url}?page[size]=300"
response = session.get(base_api_endpoint)
print(response)
print(" ")
d = response.json()
data = [item['attributes']['name'] for item in d['data']]
result = {}
sorted_result = {}

for i in data:
    result[i] = data.count(i)


sorted_value_index = np.argsort(result.values())
dictionary_keys = list(result.keys())
sorted_dict = {dictionary_keys[i]: sorted(
    result.values())[i] for i in range(len(dictionary_keys))}

sorted_d = dict( sorted(result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True))

for key, value in sorted_d.items():
    print(key)
```

For some context, this structure of dictionary is used in other areas of the program to print both the key and value pair but for simplicities sake I'm just printing the key here.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would produce different results if it returns less than the page size you request.

Comment: But I don't understand the general logic. Why are you assigning element counts to the `result` dictionary?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the desired results?

Comment: Where does the `keyError` happen? Please show the full traceback.

Comment: BTW, you can replace the `for i in data:` loop with `result = collections.Counter(data)`

Comment: @Barmar

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/{name}/Desktop/{file_name}.py", line 118, in <module>
    data = [item['attributes']['name'] for item in d['data']]
KeyError: 'data'

The data just returns the name attribute from a list of Project names from the API.
Project 1
Project 2
Project 3
etc.

If my page size is 300 and there's 299 or less project names available I get the error.

Comment: That error means that the JSON response doesn't have a `data` key. Can you show sample JSON?